# Nested for loops recursion

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, coordinates

I looked up in many places and tried to understand how to get arbitrary number of nested for loops via recursion. But what I have understood is clearly wrong.

**I need to generate coordinates in an n-dimensional space**, in a grid-pattern. The actual problem has different coordinates with different ranges, but to get simpler things right first, I have used the same, integer-stepped coordinate ranges in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void recursion(int n);

int main(){    
  recursion(3);
  return 0;
}



void recursion(int n)
{
  if(n!=0){
    for(int x=1; x<4; x++){
        cout<<x<<" ";
        recursion(n-1);
  }
}
  else cout<<endl;
}
```

I want, and was expecting the output to be:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
```

Instead, the output I'm getting is

```
1 1 1 
2 
3 
2 1 
2 
3 
3 1 
2 
3 
2 1 1 
2 
3 
2 1 
2 
3 
3 1 
2 
3 
3 1 1 
2 
3 
2 1 
2 
3 
3 1 
2 
3
```

I just can't figure out whats wrong. Any help to figure out the mistake or even another way to generate coordinates will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need recursion. Recall addition with carry from your elementary school days. But if you insist on recursion, you need to pass the prefix down to each recursive call, because you want to repeat the prefix on each line; you can't just print it once at the top, as you are doing now.

Comment: Step through it one step at a time with your debugger and watch it in action.  You'll see the error, if not how to fix it

Comment: @IgorTandetnik if you could please elaborate, it'll be great.

Answer (score 3):

[Non-recursive solution](http://ideone.com/zyTSsf) based on add-with-carry:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool addOne(int* indices, int n, int ceiling) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (++indices[i] <= ceiling) {
            return true;
        }
        indices[i] = 1;
    }
    return false;
}

void printIndices(int* indices, int n) {
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        cout << indices[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int indices[3];
    for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
      indices[i] = 1;
    }

    do {
      printIndices(indices, 3);
    } while (addOne(indices, 3, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

[Recursive solution](http://ideone.com/r3taib), salvaged from your original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void recursion(int n, const string& prefix);

int main(){    
  recursion(3, "");
  return 0;
}

void recursion(int n, const string& prefix)
{
  if (n!=0) {
    for(int x=1; x<4; x++){
        ostringstream os;
        os << prefix << x << ' ';
        recursion(n-1, os.str());
    }
  }
  else cout << prefix << endl;
}
```

Comment: The non-recursive method is really wonderful. Thank you so much :)
Also,which of the two methods will be faster?

Comment: `which of the two methods will be faster?` I leave this question as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Per Igor's comment, you need an increment function.

Let's use an `std::vector` to represent each dimension.  That is vector[0] is the first dimension, vector[1] is the second dimension and so on.

Using a vector allows us to determine the number of dimensions without any hard coded numbers.  The vector.size() will be the number of dimensions.

Here is a function to get you started:

```
void Increment_Coordinate(std::vector<int>& coordinates,
                          int               max_digit_value,
                          int               min_digit_value)
{
  unsigned int digit_index = 0;
  bool apply_carry = false;
  do
  {
    apply_carry = false;
    coordinates[digit_index]++; // Increment the value in a dimension.
    if (coordinates[digit_index] > max_digit_value)
    {
      // Reset the present dimension value
      coordinates[digit_index] = min_digit_value;
      // Apply carry to next column by moving to the next dimension.
      ++digit_index;
      apply_carry = true;
    }      
  } while (apply_carry);
  return;
}
```

**Edit 1**
This is only a foundation.  The function needs to be boundary checked.
This function does not support dimensions of varying sizes.  That is left as an exercise for reader or OP.